# WPF DataGrid Header Text Background Fill

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I can't get the Header background filled in DataGrid, as below on screenshot. I've tried stretching the Header and Summary  text to fill the the Header space etc. There is a white background above the Summary world (this goes for every Header in the grid). How do I get rid of the white space?

[image]

```
                    <DataGrid x:Name="DisplayGrid" Grid.Row="2" IsReadOnly="False" SelectionMode="Single"  SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

                    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" ></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

and the Summary column:

```
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="SummaryTextBox" Header="Summary" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100" Width="*" MaxWidth="450">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock 
                                        Text="{Binding Summary}" 
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        TextAlignment="Justify"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Edit 1:**
Adding Background removes the Grid lines from the header. It doesn't look good after that (using different background colors as well).

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" ></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

The white color is because of default style of column headers so, you have to set the Background explicitly in your style.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
```

You may use gradient colors or shadow effects if you want to have a different look than data part.